# How do I get the whole namespace for a given language, or the fallback namespace if it does not exist?

Tags: javascript, i18next

After I have successfully loaded a namespace, I would like to access it as an object for a given language.

If the namespace does not exist for the given language, I would like to get the namespace for the fallback language.

If even the namespace does not exist for the fallback language, I would like to get an empty object.

I have already tried this:

```
var ns = "abc";
var ns_obj = i18next.translator.resourceStore.data[i18next.language][ns];
```

But there must be a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the content of the translator object's ressource store directly from  `i18next` with `getResourceBundle()`.

From the [API](https://www.i18next.com/overview/api#getresourcebundle):

> **getResourceBundle**
>
> `i18next.getResourceBundle(lng, ns)`
>
> Returns a resource bundle.

To get the namespace for the given language or the fallback language, you can use:

```
var ns = "abc";
var ns_obj = i18next.getResourceBundle(i18next.language, ns)
          || i18next.getResourceBundle(i18next.options.fallbackLng[0], ns) 
          || {};
```

If you have multiple fallback languages you will have to iterate over `i18next.options.fallbackLng`.